# MVC3 JsonResult: How to disable serialization of child objects?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and one of my action methods is set up to return a Json response:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddUser(User user)
{
... do something to user and return it ...
return Json(user);
```

While processing with Entity Framework, the user object gets a few child objects. Json serializer is likely to be unable to cope with the entire object graph, and returns InvalidOperationError error (about a circular reference being identified).

I do not need any of the child objects actually, and I would like to get user serialized without child objects. How I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) to tag members you don't want serialized.

Comment: What if I will need those members in other situations? Can I control serialization process from the code?

Comment: The only other option with the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) used by the `JsonResult` is to write your own [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) implementation for your type, but you won't be able to use the `JsonResult` any longer, you would need to write your own result and register your new converter with the serializer.